# Is it possible to create sign up possibility without PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, registration

Is it possible to create a sign up possibility without PHP?
i made an application with jQuery, and i want the users to be able to sign up and
save there input. Is this possible without PHP?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you can use Java, JavaScript, Ruby, Python, C, ASP.NET or basically any other language. What you do need to have is something on the server side, that will process the request from your jQuery app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web applications consists of two sides. server and client, server is stored in some host in remote computer while we are the client who request them from our desktop.

php is a server side programming language (that runs on server) while javascript is client side language(runs on our computer). so if you want to create alert message with php then then you cannot. similarly you cannot store data on sever with javascript because it runs on your computer.

data are sent from server as request and they are manipulated on browser with css and javascript. (you are are able to see browse page with extention .php  even though you don't have php installed on your computer. beasuse server has php compiler)

now if you want to create a sign up then, you need to store data in server (because data has to be available), and javascript does on run on server. so you will need a server side language. there are lots of languages for server side scripting and that they are really good and you can choose any of them as mentioned above. But most important thing is you need one ...!

Answer (score 2):

You can use any server-side language, so strictly speaking yes, you can solve it without PHP. I assume you want this without any programming on the server side - that's not possible as far as I know.

Comment: thanks is this possible with no php programming on the server side?

Comment: Your comment is the same as the original question. The answer is still the same. Yes, you can do it without PHP. No, you can't do it without any server-side programming (as others have pointed out as well)

Answer (score 1):

You can store input in their browser's localStorage, or in a cookie if it's really small. That way users can save their stuff, but don't even have to sign up.

Otherwise, "signing up" usually implies creating some sort of account, which must be handled server side.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You still need a language on the server-side that is able to interpret your input (login and password) and compare it with your users data.

The only way to achieve this is throug a programming language on the server side. If your hosting environment is using Apache and PHP, then PHP is probably the easiest way to do it.